# Creating Cloud endpoint using terraform in cloud build

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to deploy Google cloud endpoint using terraform in cloud build.

Following is the code in my main.tf

```
resource "google_endpoints_service" "openapi_service" {
service_name   = "<endpoint_service_name>"
project        = "<my_projectname>"
openapi_config = file("openapi-spec1.yaml")
```

}

and on my cloud build I have used following code

```
- id: 'terraform-plan'
  name: hashicorp/terraform:0.12.24
  dir: 'swagger/child'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  args: 
  - '-c'
  - | 
  chmod 777 openapi-spec1.yaml
  ls -latr
  terraform plan
```

I have tested my main.tf, It works perfectly when I am trying to run from my cloud shell using `terraform apply` command.

But when I am trying to do it with cloud build it fails with

```
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": panic: time: missing Location in call to Time.In
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: 
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: goroutine 38 [running]:
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: time.Time.In(...)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/goenv/versions/1.14.3/src/time/time.go:1126
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/google.predictServiceId(0xc0003d4140, 0x237b500, 0xc000864000, 0xc000919ae0, 0xc0003d4140)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/src/github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/google/resource_endpoints_service.go:157 +0x572
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/schema.schemaMap.Diff(0xc000220ae0, 0xc000dcd5e0, 0xc000dd1620, 0x2830798, 0x237b500, 0xc000864000, 0x2c0cb00, 0x0, 0xffffffffffffffff, 0x0)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk@v1.11.0/helper/schema/schema.go:524 +0xac2
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/schema.(*Resource).simpleDiff(0xc000223440, 0xc000dcd5e0, 0xc000dd1620, 0x237b500, 0xc000864000, 0xc000dd1601, 0xc000803898, 0x40d7dd)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk@v1.11.0/helper/schema/resource.go:356 +0x85
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/helper/schema.(*Provider).SimpleDiff(0xc0000ca800, 0xc000803a80, 0xc000dcd5e0, 0xc000dd1620, 0xc000dd0360, 0xc000dd1620, 0x0)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk@v1.11.0/helper/schema/provider.go:321 +0x99
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/internal/helper/plugin.(*GRPCProviderServer).PlanResourceChange(0xc00000f4f8, 0x2c0be40, 0xc000dd0300, 0xc0003a4000, 0xc00000f4f8, 0xc000dd0300, 0xc00080eb88)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk@v1.11.0/internal/helper/plugin/grpc_provider.go:633 +0x79c
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/internal/tfplugin5._Provider_PlanResourceChange_Handler(0x26ad540, 0xc00000f4f8, 0x2c0be40, 0xc000dd0300, 0xc0007e2a20, 0x0, 0x2c0be40, 0xc000dd0300, 0xc00084b900, 0x1289)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk@v1.11.0/internal/tfplugin5/tfplugin5.pb.go:3287 +0x217
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc0005ce1a0, 0x2c3f180, 0xc000396780, 0xc00079a000, 0xc0005249f0, 0x3b49b68, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.28.0/server.go:1082 +0x50a
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc0005ce1a0, 0x2c3f180, 0xc000396780, 0xc00079a000, 0x0)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.28.0/server.go:1405 +0xcc9
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1(0xc000034b70, 0xc0005ce1a0, 0x2c3f180, 0xc000396780, 0xc00079a000)
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.28.0/server.go:746 +0xa1
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5: created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.552Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5:   /opt/teamcity-agent/work/5d79fe75d4460a2f/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.28.0/server.go:744 +0xa1
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalDiff, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [ERROR] <root>: eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [TRACE] [walkPlan] Exiting eval tree: google_endpoints_service.openapi_service
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [TRACE] vertex "google_endpoints_service.openapi_service": visit complete
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [TRACE] vertex "google_endpoints_service.openapi_service": dynamic subgraph encountered errors
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [TRACE] vertex "google_endpoints_service.openapi_service": visit complete
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "provider.google (close)" errored, so skipping
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" errored, so skipping
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020/07/23 12:58:58 [INFO] backend/local: plan operation completed
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.558Z [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=/workspace/swagger/child/.terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-google_v3.31.0_x5 pid=32 error="exit status 2"
Step #1 - "terraform-plan": 2020-07-23T12:58:58.726Z [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
```

I also checked with the IAM roles used by the cloud build. I have added Project editor role, same level of permission I tested `terraform apply` from my cloud shell.
Also added rwx permission on the swagger file to be on safe side but it didn't help in resolving the issue.

Comment: I see that there is already a fix for the aforementioned [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/6840). Please check [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/magic-modules/pull/3781).

Comment: Yes, I opened the issue. New release will fix this issue.